# Stata: options vce(robust) and vce(cluster)

Tags: econometrics, stata, robust-standard-error

I have a panel of firm data and my supervisor recommended `vce(cluster firmID)` for clustering the standard errors. However, the `vce(robust)` command yields higher significance for relevant predictor. Actually, this model has the best fit out of the OLS models. Of course, my supervisor could not predict these results beforehand, but I wonder what may explain the result and how I can argue for using robust instead, or should I include both?

Comment: In Stata terms these are options, **_not_** commands. The fit, meaning parameter estimates,  is identical across these choices. `vce()` just controls standard error calculation. Which standard errors should be calculated depends on your ideas about the generating process, not a search for best buy models driven by numerical criteria. As your question has a statistical core, I am not voting to close, but its title would seem to imply a request for coding advice, so should be rewritten. I have edited only trivially: a more drastic rewriting is up to you.

Comment: I'd ask this on Statalist where the issues will be familiar to more people, but make any cross-posting explicit.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/standard-errors-and-vce-cluster-option/).

Comment: Thank you for these suggestions. Forgive me if I am naive, my Interclass Correlation Coefficient for y, ID is 0,87 suggesting that ids can be clustered? Again, this option yields insignificant coefficients. How do I justify a different option in this case?